# Davening with a Hat and Jacket or Tefila BeSibur

Tags: halacha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [hat and jacket during davening](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2680/hat-and-jacket-during-davening)

I once a read Pesak from HaRav Shelomo Zalman Orbach where he said it was better to miss Tefila BeSibur then Daven without a hat and jacket. I read it in Mishna Berura Dirshu (Siman 90 or so) notes but they didn't say exactly why. Does anyone know why the Gaon Paskened this way?

CYLOR

Comment: We've had this question before without the why. ("Is it better to...?")

Comment: [Related](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2680/hat-and-jacket-during-davening)

Comment: I think his name was "Orbach" even to Sepharadim...

Comment: @Dave - I thought that Sefardim don't have a "ch," but they use "kh" for the letter *Chaf/Khaf* (obviously not a "kh" transliteration for *chet/het*).

Comment: What about merging the questions?

Comment: @AdamMosheh So then at least it should have been Orbakh! (The name ends with a khaf, not a het.)

Comment: @Dave it's English, IDT it matters.

Comment: @HachamGabriel One thing's for sure, his name wasn't Orbah in any language or dialect.

Comment: Merged into the other question as an answer: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17330

Comment: I just reread the Dirshu and it said the exact opposite.